# Is "calendula paddle" used in the literal sense in "The Liar's Key"?

Tags: meaning, mark-lawrence, the-red-queens-war

In *The Liar's Key* by Mark Lawrence, a banker is informing Jalan about the stock exchange process:

> ‘Stakes are purchased using the **calendula paddle** to attract the seller’s attention,’ Marco continued as if I hadn’t so much as twitched my lips. ‘Both parties then retire to one of the transaction booths after contracting a House Gold witness to officiate the paperwork. The sale must then be registered at—’

What does "calendula paddle" mean? I think it's used literally but it sounds too weird.

Comment: What does “calendula paddle” mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context is that the narrator is selling stakes “in three of the finest merchantmen beneath sail” on a “trading floor”, so “paddle” would seem to mean a bidding paddle of the kind used in auction rooms.

But “calendula” is a mystery. The only plausible explanation I can come up with is that “calendula”, the generic name of the [marigold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendula_officinalis), is intended to refer to the colour of the paddle:

> **marigold, *adj.*** Of the colour of the marigold flower, bright orange-yellow.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*</sub>

This is plausible because the trading floor is operated by “House Gold”, which seems to be a fantasy equivalent of a Renaissance banking family like the [House of Medici](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Medici). Such a family might well decorate their equipment in their house livery, which would likely be a colour close to gold, to suggest their name.

If this theory is right, it would be a misuse of the word, because although “marigold” refers to the colour as well as the flower, “calendula” does not: it refers only to the flower. But since *The Liar’s Key* is a fantasy novel, perhaps the misuse is deliberate, to give a sense of estrangement.